# WooCommerce - Display the variation name in next step

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I've been racking my brains for days and unfortunately couldn't find a solution, so I hope for your help.

I have a variable product with 3 options. For example size, color and print. When the size is selected, I would like to display it in step 2.

Example: I choose size M, then I have size M green, size M blue and size M red to choose from. If I choose red I have in step 3 size M red with dots and size M red without print to choose from.

The change of the single option I get with Javascript like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on( 'change', 'table.variations select#pa_size', function(){
```

But I don't know how to get the title of the variant in front of it and insert it again.

Many thanks!